# opencart image resize outputs blank image

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am working on a opencart project. Version 2.0.3. Opencart resizes images while displaying them in category page. But few of the **images are showing as just blank image**.Can someone let me know if there will be a problem with image name ? because if the problem is with code, other images should not get resized as well. But few are displaying correctly and few are showing as blank images.

Please let me know if you need the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this. Those images are in bmp format. Opencart will deal only with jpg, png type images. So,avoid using bmp images because when we upload images of bmp type, it will just return a blank image.